# how to check if the given local path is accessible for write in java

Tags: java, file, io

I want to check below

A) Path type: local:C:\program files\cts\ABCD_PP\dd\

1) check if the path exists
2) if path exists then check if the path is writable(means should be able to place a file on that path).

also

B) shared path:\\mdyptcmedia101\transmit\in\

will it be same procedure as local file path verificaion or different

using Jdk 1.6 in spring  project.

Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not appear the poster has tried solving it himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple.

```
String path = "..."; // Whatever the path may be
File file = new File(path);

if (file.isDirectory()) {
   // The path exists and it is a directory
   if (file.canWrite() {
       // The directory is writable
   } else {
       // The directory is not writable
   }
} else {
   // The path is not a directory, or it does not even exist
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[RTM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html): [File.isDirectory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29), [File.canWrite()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29)

Comment: There is no isWritable() method in the Java File class. You may want to change your answer to refer to the canWrite() method. I gave you a +1 anyway, for speed of answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File("...");
boolean canWrite = file.canWrite();
boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory();
```

Both detailed in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

[File I/O - Checking a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html)

```
Path path = ...;
if (Files.exists(path))
    /* the path exists */;

if (Files.isDirectory(path))
    /* the path exists and is a directory */;

if (Files.isWritable(path))
    /* the path is writable */;
```